# How to add to both sides of an equality in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

This seems like a really simple question, but I wasn't able to find anything useful.

I have the statement

```
n - x = n
```

and would like to prove

```
(n - x) + x = n + x
```

I haven't been able to find what theorem allows for this.

Comment: To clarify/confirm, `n - x = n` is a hypothesis and `(n - x) + x = n + x` is the current goal, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: You can apply the lemma `f_equal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the `rewrite` tactic (and then maybe `reflexivity`).

EDIT: more info about rewrite:

- You can `rewrite H` `rewrite -> H` to rewrite from left to right
- You can `rewrite <- H` to rewrite from right to left
- You can use the `pattern` tactic to only select specific instances of the goal to rewrite. For example, to only rewrite the second `n`, you can perform the following steps

  pattern n at 2.
  rewrite <- H.

In your case, the solution is much simpler.

Comment: In that case, how do I rewrite onto only one side of an equation?

Comment: One can also combine `pattern n at 2. rewrite <- H.` into `rewrite <- H at 2.`

Answer (score 2):

Building on @gallais' suggestion on using `f_equal`. We start in the following state:

```
n : nat
x : nat
H : n - x = n
============================
 n - x + x = n + x
```

**(1)** First variant via "forward" reasoning (where one applies theorems to hypotheses) using the `f_equal` lemma.

```
Check f_equal.
f_equal
 : forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (x y : A), x = y -> f x = f y
```

It needs the function `f`, so

```
apply f_equal with (f := fun t => t + x) in H.
```

This will give you:

```
H : n - x + x = n + x
```

This can be solved via `apply H.` or `exact H.` or `assumption.` or `auto.` ... or some other way which suits you the most.

**(2)** Or you can use "backward" reasoning (where one applies theorems to the goal).
There is also the `f_equal2` lemma:

```
Check f_equal2.
f_equal2
 : forall (A1 A2 B : Type) (f : A1 -> A2 -> B) 
     (x1 y1 : A1) (x2 y2 : A2),
   x1 = y1 -> x2 = y2 -> f x1 x2 = f y1 y2
```

We just apply it to the goal, which results in two trivial subgoals.

```
apply f_equal2. assumption. reflexivity.
```

or just

```
apply f_equal2; trivial.
```

**(3)** There is also the more specialized lemma `f_equal2_plus`:

```
Check f_equal2_plus.
(*
f_equal2_plus
  : forall x1 y1 x2 y2 : nat,
    x1 = y1 -> x2 = y2 -> x1 + x2 = y1 + y2
*)
```

Using this lemma we are able to solve the goal with the following one-liner:

```
apply (f_equal2_plus _ _ _ _ H eq_refl).
```

Comment: Remark that `apply f_equal with (f := fun t => t + x).` can also be used on the goal.

Comment: Is there a version of `f_equal` that works for Setoids?

Comment: @Langston To be able to prove the analogous lemma, we must have `f` proper, but to prove `f` is `Proper` we need the lemma. Vicious circle :) Btw, there is a tactic called `f_equiv`, which is a setoid analogue of the `f_equal` tactic -- can be useful to do "backward reasoning".

Answer (score 0):

There is a powerful search engine in Coq using patterns. You can try for example:

```
Search (_=_ -> _+_=_+_).
```